# iOS navigation best practice for adding items

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I cannot find the answer to this although I have implemented this rather a few times already, but maybe the wrong way.

Say I have an App for iOS, it has a main screen, which goes to a list, that list has a < back (to main) and an add button. Now when I click < back, I go back to main as that's the pop() from the stack. No issues so far.

Now when I click the add button, that is added to the stack as well; when I click back on that screen I go back to the list which is fine.

The problem is; when I save the new item, I want to go to the detail screen, but I don't actually want to have the add screen on the stack anymore while it will be there.  I want the < back button for the detail item pointing to the list.

I know how to do this, but what is actually the best to implement this with the navigation stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for adding elements the best practice is to present an ModalViewController. 
In this way it is not added to the stack.

**Update**

Let's take as examples simple apps that apple provide with iOS, Contacts app. When you want to add a new contact a VC is presented.
You'll need to implement "Done" or "Save" button that will dismiss the modalViewController and if you want to take the user into detail screen you could post a notification or other mechanism on dismissViewController method's completion block that will push the detail page from the list. But be careful on animations if you dismiss the modal VC animated and push the detail page animated you could get some unexpected behaviour. My proposal is to dismiss the Modal VC animated and push the detail page without animation.

Comment: Under what circumstances would this be best practice though? Please note I am not saying you are wrong I am trying to help you improve your answer by getting you to add more detail.

Comment: No problem :). I don't want to set the best practices. I take as examples simple apps that apple provide with iOS, let't take for example the contacts app. When you want to add a new contact a VC is presented. I always look for examples for questions of flow the already made apps from Apple.

Comment: So I show the Add page as ModalViewController? But then I would need to implement a manual back button for that?

Comment: You'll need to implement "done" or "save" button that will dismiss the modalViewController and if you want to take the user into detail screen you could post a notification or other mechanism on dismissViewController method's completion block that will push the detail page from the list.

Comment: @AdiPop there are certain circumstances where you would use the ModelViewController and where you wouldn't. But based on your comments you do seem to understand then to use them. May I suggest updating you answer with a bit more information because as it stands I can't bring myself to give a +1 but I think i could with more information

Answer (score 0):

You can override UINavigationController's viewControllers property after you pushed detail view controller. Just get current viewControllers property array, iterate and find the one you don't want to see and remove it. Remember to set viewControllers array again.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers